# Using small spherical balls to fill a cube and also find volume of the cube

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, area, geometric-measure-theory

Is it possible to calculate volume of a cube (with volume $L^3$) by filling it with small balls each with a radius $r_N$ and the balls are disjoint.

Let the number of balls be $N$

$$\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} r_N=0$$

Is it always possibles to have $$\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} N \frac {4\pi r_N^3}{3}=L^3$$ $\quad$

Please keep in mind we are not talking about integration in spherical coordinates .

I know Radon-Nikodym theorem [see Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) allows us to calculate the volume of the cube using small balls but not necessarily disjoint and it is not obvious that the radius of each ball is the same .

Comment: You would be able to approximate the volume. Are you filling it one ball at a time so you can get the best packing or just tipping them in and happy with any packing?

Comment: Are you asking if there is any reasonable packing arrangement for which the volume of the balls does not converge to the volume of the cube?

Comment: Do you intend that the balls in your filling should have disjoint interiors? If so, I'm pretty sure this is false, because it would be an example of a "packing problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems, and packing problems in Euclidean spaces usually have a positive lower bound to the density.

Comment: @rajb245 I'm asking if you could approximate the volume of the cube by filling it with balls and each ball has the same radius.

Comment: @LeeMosher could provide a proof that it is false. Remember the radius of the ball tends to zero as the number of balls increases

Comment: Actually, a better link than the one in my previous comment would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for your links, they are very helpful. Sadly it says the proof is 99% correct.

Comment: You misread the 99% remark. That is a reference to the level of certainty of one of the readers of the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the same as filling balls of unit radius into cubes of larger and larger side length and taking the limit as the side length goes to $+\infty$. This converts your problem into the [Kepler conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture).

The theorem of Hales and co-authors, saying that the [Kepler conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture) is true, shows that the ratio between the left and right sides of your conjectured equation is no greater than 
$$\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{2}} = 0.740480489...
$$